# Graph showing functions over the same x and y ranges

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to draw functions and have used this code. But I don't like to give every function a separate domain, I want to say this function has `ymax=4` and `ymin=-3`.
Who can help me?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, >=latex]
\draw[very thin, color=black, dotted, step=1 cm] (-7,-5) grid (7,5);
\draw[->] (-7.5,0) -- (7.5,0) node[right] {\scriptsize $x$};
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5.5) node[above] {\scriptsize $f(x)$};
\foreach \x in {-7,-6,...,7} \draw (\x, 1pt) -- (\x,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny \x};
\foreach \y in {-5,-4,...,5} \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) node[anchor=east] {\tiny \y};
\draw[color=black, very thick, domain=-2.2:2.1, samples=100]   plot (\x,{-1/3*(\x)^2})
  node[right] {\tiny $p_1$};
\draw[color=black, dashed, domain=-1.1:1.1, samples=100]   plot (\x,{1/6*(\x)^2})
    node[right] {\tiny $p_2$};
\draw[color=black, thick, domain=-2.2:2.2, samples=100]   plot (\x,{-(\x)^2})
    node[right] {\tiny $p_3$};
\draw[color=black, thin, samples=100]   plot (\x,{0.1*(\x)^2}) node[right] {\tiny $p_4$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this type of graph, I recommend using the [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package over `tikz`, which is limited in terms of control over axis range and function domain. The code below should get you started with `pgfplots`.

**Edit**: Use the `minor x tick num = n` key (and equivalents for y- and z-axes) to specify how many minor ticks ('n', here) you want between two successive major ticks. Be mindful of potential off-by-one errors: n minor ticks translate to n+1 subintervals between two successive major ticks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
    \begin{axis}%
        [
            grid=major,  
            xtick={-7,-6,...,7},  
            minor x tick num=4, % 4 minor ticks => 5 subintervals
            xmin=-6,
            xmax=6,
            xlabel={\scriptsize $x$},
            axis x line=middle,
            ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
            minor y tick num=4,  % 4 minor ticks => 5 subintervals
            ymin=-3,
            ymax=4,
            ylabel={\scriptsize $f(x)$},
            axis y line=middle,
            no markers,
            samples=100,
            domain=-6:6,
        ]
        \addplot (x,{-1/3*x^2});
        \addplot (x,{1/6*x^2});
        \addplot (x,{-x^2});
        \addplot (x,{0.1*x^2});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But it didn't worked for me. I have copied the code and made a new document to test it, but I get an error: "choice 1.8 unknown"

Comment: Thanks, I've no idea how I should do that, but I will try to find it. (using TeXpad for Mac)

Comment: @Timperman You can use `compat=newest` to use whatever the newest version in your system but nevertheless try to update to the new version and use `1.8` key which is the current new version number.

Comment: @percusse I still get errors, even with compat=newest.
TexPad is the editor, and uses a Tex distribution. I've installed TexWorks and TeXpad is using this Tex distribution. 
I'll give it a try with [http://tug.org/mactex/](http://tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: @Timperman remove that line then. And can you put `\pgfplotsversion` in the document (not preamble) to see what is installed?

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't giving anything, untill I have found how to install the updates with the Tex Live Utility. It updated 261 packages.
Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Glad percusse and I could help, but remember that [accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Is there a way to show also smaller ticks in between? Because sometimes I want 0 - 1 - 2 ... but in between 0 and 1, I want 5 stripes.

Comment: @Arne See my edit.

Comment: @Arne. That's up to you. I also tried `grid=both` but found the graph to be less readable as a result, so I reverted to `grid=major`. Please accept my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Arne. A tiny correction: if you want 5 subintervals ("stripes") between major ticks, you should set `minor x tick num` to `4`, not `5`.

Comment: @Jubobs thank you, I've already changed it in my documents. Thanks anyway.
(and I have found out how to accept an answer... new forum me, new rules and habits)