# Drawing a shape or lines on xy axes, 10 times to small

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I want to draw a rectangle on the xy axes, I need to multiply all the digits by ten. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,a4paper]{tufte-book} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage{amsmath,units} %voor wiskundige formules
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma,per-mode=fraction,exponent-product = \cdot]{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[%
title=$F(\Delta x)$-grafiek,
major grid style=gray,
axis lines=center,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=25,
xtick={0,1,...,10},
ytick={0,5,...,25},
width=\textwidth,
%height=8cm,
xlabel=$\Delta x(\si{\m})$,
ylabel=$F(\si{\N})$,
%ticks=both,
minor xtick={0,1,...,10},
minor ytick={0,1,...,25},
grid=both,
%enlarge x limits={upper},
%enlarge y limits={upper}
]
\addplot[red, very thick, domain=0:8]  {20} node[above]{$F$};
\filldraw[fill opacity=.3,fill=orange] (0,0) rectangle (80,200) ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you see the dimensions of the rectangle should be (8,20) and not (80,200)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PGFPLOTS version < 1.11

Seems like your PGFPLOTS version is < 1.11. So you should use:

**`rectangle (axis cs:8,20)`**

instead of

`rectangle (80,200)`.

## PGFPLOTS version >= 1.11

If you are using  PGFPLOTS version 1.11 or newer, `axis cs:` is not needed.

From the PGFPLOTS manual Version 1.12.1 (2.2.1
New Optional Features):

> PGFPLOTS 1.11 changes the `axis cs:` it is now the default coordinate
>   system. If you write `\draw (1,2) -- (2,2);` PGFPLOTS will
>   automatically treat it as `\draw (axis cs:1,2) -- (axis cs:2,2);`.

Comment: I always update my tex installation with Tex Live Utility, and I think I have the version 1.12.1 (I've looked at installed packages, asked info about pgfplots, and the according pdf document was marked with version 1.12.1 revision 2015/05/02. But your answer did the job. (Still makes me wondering why it doesn't work with "my version" of 1.12.1)

Comment: @Arne Have you tried `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` or `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}`?

Comment: In the preamble, there was \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} I've copied that from and older answer:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129381/graph-showing-functions-over-the-same-x-and-y-ranges But now with "newest" it works like a charm.